# Why was this access question closed as off topic, and what community would be better suited for it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I posted [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1525505/why-does-microsoft-access-keep-asking-me-to-input-parameter-values) here earlier, but it was closed as off-topic. I figured since it was access related, which is software related, this was the best fit community. If that is not the case, could someone please point me to a more suitable community?

Comment: It's a programming question. Try [so] but first improve your question as it is sadly lacking in information.

Comment: Hopefully, you will provide the Stack Overflow community with a little more detail then you provided us.

Comment: @DavidPostill
Didn't realize Access was considered programming -- I haven't really written any code, but I'll try at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ramhound
What other information do you guys feel would be relevant? I have a form with a named field that I'm trying to use as a criteria. The name and syntax for the ford and field are given in the post. I've added that Access was able to autofill the name of the form and field, so it can't be an issue of misspelling. I need to know what situations can cause parameter values to still be requested, despite the form being filled out. In my eyes, that was what was relevant.

What other information should I post with my question.